# Run autostart_console.bat on startup or new tab in ConEmu?

Tags: windows-8, cmd, conemu

I am using ConEmu (robust cmd) on Windows 8 Pro.

How/where can I set conemu to run autostart_console.bat when starting ConEmu or when opening a new tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In most cases you need to use following command in `Command line` field (Settings -> Startup).

```
cmd /k autostart_console.bat
```

If you need to start other shell (not cmd.exe), for example [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/)

```
cmd /c autostart_console.bat & far.exe
```

Full paths to autostart_console.bat or far.exe are required if they are not in `%PATH%`.

Comment: That was the trick. 
For anyone interested, I have an autostart_console.bat in a dropbox directory which is run to setup environment, etc.

Comment: I came here and realised the reason this wasn't working for me... using __"-c"__ instead of __"/c"__