# Start Conemu with project specific environment variables

Tags: conemu

I'd like to create shortcuts to open shell consoles with project specific environment variables for each shell.  I do this now with batch files like the below. They work but I need to open a CMD session and then run `setenv_AA` and `setenv_BB` every time. I'd like to just have shortcuts I can double click on and be running and ready to go. How can I do that?

Project 1 setenv_AA.bat

```
pushd D:\Projects\AA
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python27x64\
set PROMPT=[2.7_x64] $p$_$g
set path=%PYTHONHOME%;%cd%\bin;%path%
```

Project 2 setenv_BB.bat

```
pushd X:\Work\BB
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python34\
set PROMPT=[3.4] $p$_$g
set path=%PYTHONHOME%;%cd%\bin;%path%
```

What I've tried already:

A shortcut to the .bat file just runs ConEmu and than says *"Press Enter or Esc to close console..."*.
`"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd D:\project_aa\setenv.bat` does the same.

A shortcut like `"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe" /cmd set path=NEW;%path%;` yields *"ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=0. Press Enter or Esc to close console..."*

Using `/k /cmd` yields a popup message of "unrecognized switch" while `/cmd /k` reveals it's calling CMD with `/c` (terminate after run):

```
'/k' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Current directory:
D:\p\ytdemv3.2016-03-08

Command to be executed:
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C /k set path=NEW;...blah...blah

ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

How to change /C to /K?

Comment: Ideal would be that whenever ConEmu starts it looks for `.conemurc` (or whatever) in the current folder and runs the contents. This would enable per-folder custom shells from Explorer right-click context "ConEmu here..." and bypass the need to create shortcuts.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372299/run-autostart-console-bat-on-startup-or-new-tab-in-conemu (but instead of location specific settings it refers to global settings for every new session, more like an autoexec.bat from days of old).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, ConEmu is not a `cmd.exe`, so your `/c` or `/k` have no sense at all.

Use `...\ConEmu.exe /cmd cmd.exe /k your-batch.bat`.

As for per-folder ".conemurc", that is rather bad idea. These conmands have to be executed per tab, but not globally. Also, these commands must be shell-specific and must be executed by the shell started in that tab. So, this idea doesn't differ from batch started with /k switch.

Comment: Thanks! It was not understanding that I needed to both `/cmd` and `cmd.exe` that tripped me up. I though that `/cmd` was shorthand for calling cmd.exe. The .rc file was just me wondering of ways to avoid creating both a batch file and a shortcut for each project folder. You're the one to know if it's a bad idea though so away with it. ;-)